# Scala and line endings in string templates

Tags: scala, eol, os-dependent

I am writing acceptance test, which validates HTTP response from embedded server. So it looks like

```
assert((200, """{
                |  "status" : "OK"
                |}""".stripMargin) === (code, response))
```

so far it works quite well on my Linux box,  however when the test is invoked on Windows - it fails.

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: "{[
  "status" : "OK"
]
}" did not equal "{[
  "status" : "OK"]
}"
```

I think this is because of line endings - those are different in Windows than in Linux. Is there any simple way to provide os-specific line endings in compiled test data?

Comment: It seems like your success criteria is much too tight. You should treat the response according to the spec, including all white-space variation tolerance.

Comment: it should be so actually, this is kind of reference specification testing.

Comment: What specification are you testing? I can't see how you want a test like this...

Comment: this is [SI-3101](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3101)

Answer (score 1):

Check for both. Cuz "Most textual Internet protocols (including HTTP, SMTP, FTP, IRC and many others) mandate the use of ASCII CR+LF (0x0D 0x0A) on the protocol level, but recommend that tolerant applications recognize lone LF as well. "

Enjoy.

Comment: actually it's just for tests, and I have no idea how to do that in neat way

Comment: strings constants glued by "\r\n" and "\n"? Or replace "\r\n" with "\n" and assert after that

Comment: that's what I've done, will see if that will help. But I don't like the solution here, I believe that line endings should be os-dependent.

Comment: Well they are, but if I understand your use-case correctly it depends on the platform your http-container installed. So you have no certainty what exactly the answer will be.